# Trig Identities to solve Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a problem in my workbook I can't grasp. [image]

I need some headers on what to look for/ where to start before I get myself confused.

Comment: Can you use some trig function to compute $\alpha$ and $\beta?$ Then use the fact that the angles in a triangle add up to $180^\circ$ to find $\theta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

Notice that angle $ACB = 90 - \alpha$ and angle $GEF = 90 - \beta$. From here, show angle $DCE = 90 - \alpha$ and angle $CED = 90 - \beta$. Now that you know all the angle measures in triangle $CDE$, they should add together to get $180$, which will lead you to your first answer.

For the second part, use the addition identity for tangent.

$$ \tan(\theta) = \tan(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{\tan(\alpha)+\tan(\beta)}{1-\tan(\alpha)\tan(\beta)}.$$

You can find $\tan(\alpha)$ and $\tan(\beta)$ from the "upper" right triangles.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.. I got $\theta = tan (\alpha) + tan (\beta) $ Is that the same?

Comment: You are welcome. That is not the same.

Comment: I figured it out soon after, thank you again.

Comment: @Revinous Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Draw vertical lines through B, F, D. Now it will be obvious that $\alpha + \beta = \theta$

You know $\tan \alpha$ and $\tan \beta$. Use

$$\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \dfrac{\tan \alpha + \tan \beta}{ 1-\tan \alpha \tan \beta}$$